# Android application which gives out location based suggestions for hotels, restaurants, mode of transport available

Tags: android

I am planning to build an Android application which gives out location based suggestions for hotels, restaurants, mode of transport available for that particular city. Are there any free services available or any APIs maybe that could help me build the same?

Answer (score 0):

May be foursquare API would help you..

https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/

Comment: I did not use yelp but May be that would be sufficient for you. As per my development experience I used foursquare API and it provide a lot and best results but it's total up to you.